# What level of politeness is お出でになる

Tags: jlpt, keigo, sonkeigo

I am prepping for my JLPT N5 exam in December and one of the prep tests I was reviewing threw お出でになる at me. Jisho.org says it is sonkeigo for いる
くる and いく, but I always thought that the sonkeigo for those was いらっしゃる.

Any clarification on when/how おいでになる is used would be most welcome.

Also colour me surprised that any keigo is getting thrown at me in an N5 prep; I thought keigo, modest, and humble speech was N4 material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically both are 尊敬語 and equally polite.

In fact they refer to each other in the definitions.

> [いらっしゃる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%84%E3%82%89%E3%81%A3%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%82%8B/)
>
> 1. 「行く」「来る」「居る」の尊敬語。おいでになる。「休日にはどこへ―・るのですか」「先生が―・った」「明日は家に―・いますか」

> [おいでになる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%BE%A1%E5%87%BA%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B/)
>
> 1. 「行く」「来る」「居る」の尊敬語。いらっしゃる。「日曜日は教会へ―・るそうです」「もう―・るころだろうとお待ちしておりました」「明日はお宅に―・りますか」

For example,

- 休日はどこへいらっしゃるのですか＝休日はどこへおいでになるのですか
- 先生がいらっしゃった＝先生がおいでになった
- もういらっしゃるころだろうとお待ちしておりました＝もうおいでになるころだろうとお待ちしておりました etc.

---

I think いらっしゃる is more common, and in that sense おいでになる sounds a bit politer (or too polite outside hotels etc.).